# Toast message doesn't show up/ Strange Emulator behavior with Kotlin and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, toast

In a new Project, I'm not able to see a Toast message on the Home Screen.

Also, I noticed that Emulator Home Screen has strange behaviors, like bottom buttons disappeared and background screen is black.

I've tried many many things already suggested on Stackoverflow (restart and invalidate IDE cache, call applicationContext, requireContext and context letting it be nullable, etc.) but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by clicking "Tools" from Android Studio menu, then "Device Manager", next click on the 3 dots menu at right of the device listed and finally

> Cold Boot Now

The Toast worked calling the Fragment Context by

```
requireContext()
```